# I'm looking for a sutta which mentions nationalism

Tags: sutras, texts

I remember a sutta which uses the word "nationalism" in reference to a taint to be removed. It was the last in a certain sequence of taints. I think i read it on access to insight.

However, when i search for the word i can't find any such sutta in either dhamma talks or access to insight. Or anywhere else for that matter.

Can someone *ahem* enlighten me?

Comment: Jati, usually translated as birth is even today the word for nation (a modern definition) or race. So it's up to the translator and when ever reading birth it can be transated to race as well.

Answer (score 1):

On [this page](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/index.html), you can find Thanissaro Bhikkhu's summary for [MN 93](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.093.than.html):

> The Buddha enters into a debate with a brahman on whether one's worth
>   as a person is determined by birth or by behavior. Although some of
>   the arguments he presents here deal with the specifics of brahman
>   caste pride, many of them are applicable to issues of racism and
>   nationalism in general.

Comment: Thanks. But i'm looking for one which mentions nationalism by name.

Comment: Maybe it can't exactly "mention nationalism by name" -- e.g. I suppose that "nation" is a modern word. Maybe it's a conceit though (see e.g. answers to [this topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9415/254)).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [DN 31](https://suttacentral.net/dn31/en/sujato):

> *When a noble disciple is not prejudiced by favoritism, hostility, stupidity, and cowardice,*
>
> *Yato kho, gahapatiputta, ariyasāvako neva chandāgatiṃ gacchati, na dosāgatiṃ gacchati, na mohāgatiṃ gacchati, na bhayāgatiṃ gacchati;*